# Convert plural to singular and visa versa

Tags: discussion

Can anyone please help me find an ONLINE singular to plural (and visa versa) converter that will convert a list of words at once? I've found plenty that do one word at a time.

There are so many online text/word manipulaters out there, I'm surprised that I can't find one for singular and plural conversations.

Comment: Note that it's [vice versa](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vice-versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my PHP peeps:

Use the Laravel function [`Str::plural()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-plural). You can even [run Laravel code online](https://phpsandbox.io/), no downloads.

(The code for this is very simple. I may edit to include it later.)

Answer (score 1):

Found .NET PluralizationServices and Humanizer: https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/blob/main/readme.md#pluralize.

Comment: Try to pluralize *visa versa*!